# How is "rack" (as in billiards or pool) expressed?

Tags: words

In pool/billiards, "to rack" means to set up the game by placing the balls into the triangle frame. What is the corresponding (technical) term in Japanese if any?

I came up (via circumlocution) with:

> ビリヤードの球を三角形の枠に並べる

Is there a better way to express this? Alternatively I suppose 準備 and its synonyms would work to describe "preparing the game for play". But it's not specific to pool/billiards.

Comment: Good thing you clarified you weren't after the "chi chi" style rack!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wiki says it is usually expressed like 「ラックする」「ラックを組む【くむ】」「ラックを立てる【たてる】」.

See also: [ラック (ビリヤード)](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF_%28%E3%83%93%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%29)

Comment: @dainichi-san, Thanks, you two are so sweet~~^^